# RequestMapping failing in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I have tried just about everything to try and figure out what is going on here. I cannot get my controller to respond to the url I am entering and continue to get HTTP 404 errors.

URL I am using - `http://localhost:8080/projectHub/getHomepage.html`

Directory - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z90r3.jpg

projectHub-servletConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.projectHub.controllers"></context:component-scan>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

homepage.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>ProjectHub Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>${titleHomepage}</h1>
    <p>WTF</p>

</body>
</html>
```

ProjectHubController.java

```
@Controller
public class ProjectHubController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/getHomepage")
    public String getHomepage(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("titleHomepage", "ProjectHub");

        return "homepage";
    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>ProjectHub</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>projectHub</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/projectHub-servletConfig.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>projectHub</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Try the URL without ".html"

Comment: that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you also incorporate the change from the other answer?

Comment: The set up looks correct. how are you deploying your app ? make sure the name of the war is "projectHub".

Comment: @Reddy I am right clicking on the project itself and simply running on server.

Comment: could i be using the wrong url?

Comment: yes because the set up worked fine for me. Please check the context path.

Answer (score 0):

I think your url pattern in web.xml is wrong. It should be "/*" and not "/".

Comment: Why do you _think_ so?

Answer (score -1):

Http URLs are case sensitive. Is the projectHub in your URL had capital P or small ? Try with P uppercase.
Also do not use .html at end.
If problem persists also share server sysouts.